# Mapbox gl expressions

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I can't understand how to use new mapbox expressions.
For example if I need something like this one:

set circle-radius to 10 if prop 'store' is more than 0 and less than 500

set circle-radius to 20 if prop 'store' is grater than 500

how can I do it with expressions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a case expression, this could do it:

```
[
  'case',
  ['all', ['>', ['get', 'store'], 0], ['<', ['get', 'store'], 500]],
  10,                 
  ['>', ['get', 'store'], 500],
  20, 
  0
];
```

See the documentation here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions-case